# Is Node.js compatible with Oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle, node.js, oracle11g, compatibility

I've searching for this, but I couldn't find anything.

In a university project, we should specify the technologies that we're gonna use for a project given to us, and it's a big project, so we consider to use `Oracle`
and for the server, we consider `Node.js`, but, are they compatible?
I've found that is compatible with `9i`, but nothing abour this `11g` version

Comment: I just want to chime in and ask why Oracle? Its a hugely expensive database licensed per-core (the community edition is hugely restrictive). There are some great features, but for most applications something like Postgres is going to be overkill. I realize you're researching, but why Node.js? Think that one through as well. It is a single event loop so it can be ultra fast and really slow depending on your code. These two technologies are polar opposites of the Free Software world.

Comment: is not the unique alternative, we're considering. We choose for Oracle because it's a huge project (an entire city, with a requerimient of 24 millon transactions per day) and it's for the state, so official support will be something desirable. About Node.js, I had never used it, it's a suggestion from a team co-worker. We are considering distinct alternatives, and we need to choose. This is an alternative, but first we need to see if they can work, after that, see if they are a good choice

Comment: It's for the university, an ideal situation, we're not really gonna do this project (becuase allready exists :P, so based on that we got those requerimients)

Comment: http://rockycode.com/blog/connect-nodejs-oracle-say-what/
See if that get's you started. I'd definitely say "possible". And in the real world I'd say Node.js is probably the wrong choice for an app like that. Its fantastic for rapid development and slightly more than annoying to maintain.

Comment: thanks ! Knowing that they are compatible, they are an alternative to consider. Also, thanks for the advices ! Post it as an answer so I can tick it ;)

Comment: Don't worry about it--good luck specifying it.

Comment: @DanielChapman im the co-worker. we are looking for server side transaction processing options, node.js was one of the options. we are somewhat lost looking for benchmarks, or any other info about the available options. thank you for info!

Comment: Almost all frameworks and servers have transaction processing. Its all about what grain and style you want. I have a bias for JSF/Java stacks as I find them portable, reliable and fast. But just like anything in the realm of computers there are opinions on it. Benchmarks are misleading. Node.js functions off of a "single thread (not entirely accurate)" that allows for rapid responses--if they don't block--which they often do. Take a look at most large applications. They are either using .NET stack or Java. There are notable exceptions (Facebook/Google etc...)